# How can I make that layout is not crop in height

Tags: android, layout

How can I make that layout is not crop in height? For example, if I will move up contentLayout, part of the screen that do not fit on the screen will be crop. ScrollView not suitable. Because I write a component and need to control the behavior of

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
 <TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
<TextView
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:text="TextView">
</TextView>
... so many elements
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put everything in `ScrollView`.

Answer (score 1):

Change you root layout from LinearLayout to ScrollView. This way if the content doesn't fit on the screen, you're still able to scroll a little bit down to see the bottom of your layout as well.

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:text="TextView1"/>

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="TextView2"/>

    <TextView
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="TextView3"/>
<!-- And your other TextViews -->
</ScrollView>
```

BUT if you have a lot of TextViews(say 20, 50 or more), my advice is to use a ListView instead of adding each TextView separately.

[Here](http://androidexample.com/Create_A_Simple_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=65&aaid=90) you have a really basic example of how to use ListView in Android.

Comment: ScrollView not suitable. Because I write a component and need to control the behavior of

Comment: You can control pretty much anything you want, no matter if it is a  LinearLayout or a ScrollView.

Comment: I'm writing a component that is similar to the ScrollView, but with the effect of parallax. I need to know the height of the cropped area is not to then put this value in the layout_height or to Automatic layout stretched.